# Python class changer

Tags: python, architecture, coding-style, metaprogramming

I need class runtime class declaration from database.

Some class need override field and  redeclaration.

models.py

```
class Staff(object):
    name = StringField( verbose_name = "Full name")
    age = IntegerField( verbose_name = "Age")
```

utils.py

```
def class_changer(class_path, field_key, new_Field):
    pass
    ??????
```

```
>>> class_changer("models.Staff", "gender", BooleanField()) # Add new field to Staff
>>> class_changer("models.Country", "name", StringField()) # Add new class with name field
>>> class_changer("models.Staff", "country", ForeignKey("Country")) # Add new field to Staff
```

result is

```
class Staff(object):
    name = StringField( verbose_name = "Full name")
    age = IntegerField( verbose_name = "Age")
    gender = BooleanField()
    country = ForeignKey("Country")

class Country(object):
    name = StringField()
```

How to implement class_changer?

Comment: combination of `setattr` & `eval` may help you - not robust but easy to implement

Comment: i found too many method. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming eval , setattr, decorator .... But i am not sure how witch method better???. i not have few experience.

Comment: It's clear that you're doing this with django so you should be aware that thinking about doing this hurts my head because of all the metaclasses that they use: everything is connected to everything else. I'm normally a pretty happy go lucky programmer too but I'm going to just walk away from this one. I recommend that you do as well and think of a better architecture. What are you trying to actually accomplish?

Comment: well, I am trying to build Dynamic Model class. But not Django model. I am using use http://mongoengine.org/ and Django url, view, template, etc... MongoEngine ModelClass is like django ModelClass.  Mongomodel class is much easier than modelclass, u can try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need better architecture for this, but as a starting solution you may try this,

```
In [12]: class a1(object):
   ...:     pass

In [13]: def class_changer(cls_path, attr, val):
   ....:     try:
   ....:         obj = eval(cls_path)
   ....:         setattr(obj, attr, val)
   ....:     except:
   ....:         raise 
   ....:     
In [14]: def getGender(self):
   ...:     return True


In [15]: class_changer('a1','getGender', getGender)

In [16]: a1().getGender()
Out[16]: True
```

Comment: Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice), especially the accepted answer and discussion around it, to understand some of the risks and caveats of `eval`. This is not to say that the solution is bad, but you should know what you are getting into.

Comment: yeah eval is harmfull thats truth all should know, but exactly when users's input is gonna evaluated, if programmer writes eval for his own purpose - then regardless of statement it shouldn't be considered as risk - it should be considered as flexibility or programmer's choice or feature whatever....

Answer (score 1):

First adding new attributes to a class:

```
>>> class_changer("models.Staff", "gender", BooleanField()) # Add new field to Staff
>>> class_changer("models.Staff", "country", ForeignKey("Country")) # Add new field to Staff
```

For these two, just go ahead and set `Staff` directly:

```
models.Staff.gender = BooleanField()
models.Staff.country = ForeignKey("Country")
```

Or to make it generic:

```
def add_to_class(cls, name, attr):
    setattr(cls, name, attr)

add_to_class(models.Staff, "gender", BooleanField())
add_to_class(models.Staff, "country", ForeignKey("Country"))
```

Second, creating a new class:

```
>>> class_changer("models.Country", "name", StringField()) # Add new class with name field
```

You can create a class in a function and then assign it to a module:

```
def new_class(mod, name):
    class New(object): pass
    setattr(mod, name, New)

new_class(test, "Country")
add_to_class(test, "Country", StringField())
```

I'm not sure you'd want to combine `new_class` and `add_to_class`, but I suppose you could do:

```
def create_if_needed_and_add_to_class(mod, clsname, attrname, value):
    if clsname not in dir(mod):
        new_class(mod, clsname)
    add_to_class(mod, attrname, value)
```

and then finally for your `class_changer`:

```
def class_changer(mod_clsname_string, attrname, value):
    modname, clsname = '.'.split(mod_clsname_string)
    create_if_needed_and_add_to_class(globals()[modname], clsname, attrname, value)
```

Edit: fixed `class_changer` to use `locals()` for module name lookup, since it is a string and not a module.

Edit: oops, it should be `globals()`.

Comment: That is great. Very useful for me and Understanding python special features.